не подключается swagger на java
Народ всем привет, я использую чистый spring (без boot) и никак не могу подключить Swagger. Есть такие зависимости
 <swaggeer.version>3.0.0</swaggeer.version>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>${swaggeer.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>${swaggeer.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${swaggeer.version}</version>
    </dependency>

и такой AppConfig
   @Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.yaml")
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yamlProperties() {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        yaml.setResources(new ClassPathResource("application.yaml"));
        return yaml;
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean yaml = yamlProperties();
        yaml.afterPropertiesSet();
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Objects.requireNonNull(yaml.getObject()).getProperty("database.driver-class-name"));
        dataSource.setUrl(yaml.getObject().getProperty("database.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(yaml.getObject().getProperty("database.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(yaml.getObject().getProperty("database.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate() {
        return new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db/changelog/changelog-master.xml");
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.example.web"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("Car shop")
                .description("API для управления магазином по продаже автомобилей.")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

но при попытке перейти по ссылке http://localhost:28087/swagger-ui/ (tomcat работает у меня на порту 28087) всегда браузер выдает 404, а в логах
14:46:41.251 [http-nio-28087-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- GET "/swagger-ui/", parameters={}
14:46:41.286 [http-nio-28087-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping -- Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/webjars/]]
14:46:41.295 [http-nio-28087-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler -- Resource not found
14:46:41.296 [http-nio-28087-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet -- Completed 404 NOT_FOUND

подскажите добрые люди как подключить swagger

насколько я помню адрес сваггера - /swagger-ui/index.html, а не просто /swagger-ui/

я исправил путь на /swagger-ui/index.html, но теперь другая ошибка Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

Возможно, тут похожая проблема https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155420/springfox-swagger-ui-html-unable-to-infer-base-url-caused-by-missing-cookies

спасибо добрый человек, да я тут нашел решение проблемы

Правильный путь /swagger-ui/index.html

я исправил путь на /swagger-ui/index.html, но теперь другая ошибка Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

Это произошло со мной, я использовал SpringBoot 1.5.16 и Springfox 2.9.1.

В моем application.propertiesя определил server.servlet-path=/api, но, каким-то образом, swagger-ui игнорировал определенное значение. Я перепробовал много разных способов заставить это работать, и, наконец, нашел обходной путь:
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
@Bean
public Docket apiMonitoramento() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()                                  
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
            .build()    
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
}

private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()              
            .title("REST API")
            .description("Servicesx")               
            .build();
}

@Override
protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}

}
